# Angularjs dynamic add and remove input

Tags: angularjs

My code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r23Sn/28/).

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input>
  <button ng-click='add()'>Add</button>
  <br/>
  <b>Items Added Below</b>
  <div ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <input ng-model='item' id='item-{{$index}}' class='input-{{$index}}'/>
    <button ng-click='del($index)'>DEL</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Angular Controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.newitem = '';
  $scope.add = function(){
    if ($scope.items.length < 4) {
      $scope.items.push($scope.newitem);
    }
  }
  $scope.del = function(i){
    $scope.items.splice(i,1);
  }
}
```

I try to dynamic add input by ng-click and remove specific but always delete last input..
I think its because they are not distinguish in items array.
How I can fix this ?

Comment: My slightly modified fiddle shows that you are incorrect.  If I add the value to "newitem" so that I can see what I am deleting, it properly deletes the item I tell it to delete.  http://jsfiddle.net/9j34dnpo/

Comment: why are you using angular 1.0.1?

Comment: Still not delete specific input but always the last one :/
@Ronnie on my project I use newer versions :) You think the problem is version of angularjs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine as you want.

just a single mistake you have not add ng-model on input for newitem.

[Look JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yunf44nt/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp"> 
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input ng-model="newitem">
  <button ng-click='add()'>Add</button>
  <br/>
  <b>Items Added Below</b>
  <div ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <input ng-model='item' id='item-{{$index}}' class='input-{{$index}}'/>
    <button ng-click='del($index)'>DEL</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.newitem = '';
  $scope.add = function(){
    if ($scope.items.length < 4) {
      $scope.items.push($scope.newitem);
    }
  }
  $scope.del = function(i){
    $scope.items.splice(i,1);
  }
}
```

Comment: its your code i tell the issue in it..:)
what exactly you want..?

Comment: Delete specific input.. On yours jsfiddle I can add only one input, then add button don't work..

Comment: it because you are adding duplicate values.
you have to put validation on your code for 1 new entry at a time with same valuee.

Comment: its a concept of repeater to add distinct id in ng-repeat for mg-model..:)
It's not issue with your delete..
Issue with the validation.you have to write your code accordingly.

Comment: @AkshayDhankhar is right about duplicates, I'd add that to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts to this:

1. You aren't binding your first input (next to the add). This means you are only adding '' to the array. As far as I know, angularjs tracks by keys, not index by default. This leads me to part 2.
2. You are using an old AngularJS version, which according to the [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.1/docs-1.0.1/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat) has no option to "{expr} track by $index". Look at [1.4.4 docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes) for information on this.

So I'd probably use the latest stable AngularJS and make sure your first input binds to $newitem.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following fiddle :

`fiddle ::`http://jsfiddle.net/4zt4ynzL/

The problem was that you are pushing the empty string in the array every time.

As I have shown in the above fiddle, I have pushed a new value on every click of add button.

P.S. : You were doing it all correct :)

Answer (score 0):

In simple way you can use this:

**HTML:**

```
<span ng-repeat="hobby in hobbies track by $index">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type='text' ng-model='hobbies[$index]' class="form-control pull-right"/>
        <button ng-click = "addHobby()" ng-show="$last">+</button>
        <button ng-click = "removeHobby($index)" ng-show="hobbies.length > 1">-</button>
    </div>
</span>
```

**Angular Controller:**

```
$scope.hobbies = [''];

$scope.addHobby = function() {
    $scope.hobbies.push('');
}

$scope.removeHobby = function(index) {
    if(index >= 0){
        $scope.hobbies.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```